# Have any git extension Tool can be use in Visual Studio 2010？

Tags: visual-studio, git

i'm look for Git tool can be use with Visual Studio 2010?
But I yet to find any available tools, whether there is such a tool? How to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the appropriately named [Git Extensions](http://Code.google.com/p/gitextensions).  In addiition to providing add-ons for Visual Studio 2010 (and 2005 & 2008) integration it has a Windows Explorer extension **and** has a standalone GUI client.

Comment: Git EXtensions maybe the only one can be use in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

In addition to GitExtensions, you can also get [Git Source Control Provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/) that integrates into Visual Studio's Solution Explorer.